# How and which linker/proces is using 'sh' prefixed flags SH_LDFLAGS

Tags: gcc, ld

Example: `SH_LDFLAGS="-Wl,-z,relro`

and link: http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-cvs-commits/2006-May/msg00608.html

Also Go language is using prefixed flags `CGO_CFLAGS` and `CGO_LDFLAGS` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
SH_CFLAGS Flags to use compiling sources destined for a shared library
SH_LDFLAGS Flags to use linking a shared library
SHOBJ_CFLAGS Flags to use compiling sources destined for a shared object
SHOBJ_LDFLAGS Flags to use linking a shared object, undefined symbols allowed
SHOBJ_LDFLAGS_R - as above, but all symbols must be resolved
SH_LINKFLAGS Flags to use linking an executable which will load shared objects
LD_LIBRARY_PATH Environment variable which specifies path to shared libraries
```